# How to remove extra space under paragraph in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, positioning

With HTML and CSS I have this vertical space between a p tag and an image. It looks like this:

[image]

See that extra vertical space between the hello and the image? How do i remove that? I know I can absolutely position the image closer up to the hello but I would like to know what's causing the space.

My code:

HTML:

```
<div class="Box">
    <p> hello </p><img class="contextimg" WIDTH="50" HEIGHT="50"  SRC="pic.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Box                           //this is the parent div
{
    background-color:red;
    width:60px;
    margin:0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding:0px;


}
.contextimg                            //this is for the image
{
    position:relative;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    line-height:0px;

}
```

Note: I've also tried to set the body's margin and padding to 0 but it didn't work.

Comment: why  `margin-bottom: 0px;` when you are   `margin:0px;` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's common for browsers to give paragraphs a default margin. So just take it away.

Give the `<p>` a margin of 0:

```
.Box p{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/aG27X/

Answer (score 4):

That's the default padding/margin of `p` element, try using

```
.Box p {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

You should reset browser defaults before designing any webpage, if you want a quick solution than using

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Will suffice your needs, you can also google out for CSS reset stylsheets, these stylesheets will reset each elements precisely

Answer (score 1):

Set the padding and margin top/bottom of the `<p>` tag to 0. `<p>` tags automatically have a default padding/margin set, in case you dont overwrite it by something else.

```
p {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`p` stands for paragraph. the `paragraph` automaticly adds space like this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CLfV8/)

and you can remove it like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CLfV8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you what your problem is, but from this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u6C9E/

```
p { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any image above and/or bottom of the paragraphs, make the paragraphs in two class.

HTML:

```
<p> class="first">Your 1st Paragraph</p>
<p> class="second">Your 2nd Paragraph</p>
```

The CSS :

```
    p.first {
        text-indent: 2em;
        margin-bottom: -5%;
    }
    p.second {
        margin-top: -5%;
        text-indent: 2em;
    }
```

Use "**%**" to let it still looking good in responsive web...