# How to remove the automatic gap created by paragraph and header tags

Tags: css

Apparently I have to set my parent elements overflow property to hidden just to keep the browser from creating a gap between it and the top of the view port. But even with that the gap just transfers to the target element.
Should I just avoid using headers and paragraphs and use spans and divs instead?

```css
body {
  background-color: #3A3C3D;
  margin: 0;
}

.backDrop {
  background-color: #aca;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: auto;
  position: abolute;
}
```

```html
    <div class="backDrop">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4p3xotb8/2/

EDIT: Styling the elements margin property fixed my issue. I thought it would be more complicated because of what I'd read about margin collapsing and everything. I even added an overflow property to the parent element. None of this was needed. Simply editing the margin property of the target tag keeps it from interfering with other style implementations. Thank you!

Comment: You saw the warning about posting a link to jsFiddle without posting your code in your question, yet you chose to try and trick the system by adding meaningless code to get around it. Why?

Comment: Because I don't know the problem well enough to highlight the code here, and my best guess is that the only relevant code is the paragraph tag.

Comment: Regardless, post the code you have tried in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove extra space under paragraph in HTML/CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561161/how-to-remove-extra-space-under-paragraph-in-html-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the margin and add a padding instead:

```
h1,p{
  margin:0;
  padding:10px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4p3xotb8/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

CSS comes packaged with applied rules to some HTML markup. The issue you are seeing sounds like a margin or padding issue.

Try setting to the h1 element

```
h1 {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: I realized as soon as I hit the ask button that I left out my example. Corrected.

Comment: Edited my comment with what I believe to be your answer